# Find recurrence relation and evaluate the complexity

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I have 2 pseudo-code and I need to know how to write recurrence relations of code and how to evaluate the complexity.
The first one is below.

```
F(n)
if n=0 or n=1 then
   s←n
else
   a←F((n + 1) / 2)
   b←F((n + 1) / 2 - 1)
if(n mod 2 == 0) then
   s←a * (a + 2 * b)
else
   s←a * a + b * b
```

The second one is below.

```
P(x,n)
if n==0 then
   return 1
else
   partial = P(x,n//2)
   result = partial * partial
   if n % 2 == 1 then
      result *= x
return result
```

If anyone can do this and tell the solution step by step, I would be really appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In both cases, you just need to figure out how many recursive calls there are. The easiest is `P(x,n)`. How many recursive calls are there? We keep replacing `n` with `n//2` until `n` is 0. How many times does it take to go from `n` to 1 by dividing by 2 repeatedly? The answer is `log_2(n)`. So the number of recursive calls of `P(x,n)` is log_2(n), and the complexity is O(log(n)).

Comment: For `F(n)` it's slightly more complicated. The recursive calls also divide `n` by 2, but there are two recursive calls at every step. If you draw a diagram, you will realise the recursive calls form a binary tree. By the same argument as for `P(x,n)`, the height of the binary tree is log_2(n). So the question is, how many nodes are there in a binary tree of a given height? The answer is, about `2**h`, where h is the height. So the number of recursive calls from F(x,n) is about 2**log_2(n), which is about n. So the complexity of F(x,n) is O(n).

Comment: Alright, I have understand the complexity solution. It is looking like a non-recursive function. I.e. for(int i=0i<n;n/2) variable n is decrease  by power of 2. So the complexity is logn.

Comment: So can we write the recurrence equation? Like T(n)=.... ?

Comment: Yes to both your comments.

Comment: I couldn't find recurrence equation. Can you help me about that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

```
F(n)                  ----------------------T(n)
if n=0 or n=1 then    --------------  1
   s←n                --------------  1
else
   a←F((n + 1) / 2)    --------------T(n/2)
   b←F((n + 1) / 2 - 1) -------------T(n/2)
if(n mod 2 == 0) then  --------------  1
   s←a * (a + 2 * b)   --------------  1
else
   s←a * a + b * b     --------------  1
```

Which means,

```
T(n) = T(n/2) +T(n/2) + 1 + 1 +1 + 1 

 T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + C  

 using master theorem

 T(n) = O(n)
```

**Second :**

```
P(x,n)                  -----------------------------T(n)
if n==0 then                   --------------  1
   return 1                    --------------  1
else
   partial = P(x,n/2) ----------------------T(n/2)
   result = partial * partial  --------------  1
   if n % 2 == 1 then          --------------  1
      result *= x              --------------  1
return result                  --------------  1
```

which means,

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + C

using master theorem

T(n) = O(log_2 n)     [log_2 --> log base 2]
```

**Note : 1 means constant time, C can be treated as 1, not that its going to make any change while solving, also we could have used recursion tree instead of master theorem. Just that master theorem was easier.**